# Installing the Subversion Plugin in studio Version: 7.4.2 fails

Tags: anypoint-studio, mule4

Installing the Subversion Plugin in studio Version: 7.4.2 fails.
Tried with http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x and other versions too.

Answer (score 0):

The site http://subclipse.tigris.org appears to be abandoned, and subclipse 1.6 is an old version that is probably not compatible with the Eclipse version used for Studio 7.4.2. According to the [release notes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/studio/anypoint-studio-7.4-with-4.2-runtime-update-site-2-release-notes#whats-new) it is based on Eclipse 4.9. You should look for an updated version of subclipse that is compatible with that Eclipse version.

It seems that the current home of Subclipse is this GitHub project: https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse. Try installing from their distributions: https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/wiki#installation